# Android GPS Check Crashing?

Tags: android, crash, gps

Searched around extensively since yesterday and can't find anyone with this problem:

I created a GPS check function that simply returns true or false indicating whether or not the GPS is on. This works just fine in android 2.2 and 4.1 on the emulator and on a phone running 4.1.

The function is the following:

```
    private Boolean checkGPSEnabled(){
        try{
            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            if(provider.toLowerCase().contains("gps")){
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The problem is, when GPS is enabled when performing this check on the Android emulator, the emulator crashes outright.

Here is what is printed out in the LogCat when the error occurs:

```
10-12 15:23:45.593: W/dalvikvm(899): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  ... 11 more
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:660)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:482)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at com.desmill.taxi.activity.TaxiCaller.callTaxi(TaxiCaller.java:52)
10-12 15:23:45.644: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  ... 14 more
```

Any ideas? How do I get it to show the other errors where it says ...14 more...?
Thanks!

Comment: The root of the problem appears to be on line 52 in TaxiCaller class. `at com.desmill.taxi.activity.TaxiCaller.callTaxi(TaxiCaller.java:52)` Is it the code above? If not, please post this code.

Comment: This question is also similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901767/eclipse-logcat-window-cuts-off-exception-stack-traces

Comment: @Sam Well, apparently I don't know how to read a debugger. I thought the error was happening in this function, which is called BEFORE like 52 in the same class. Truth is, when GPS is enabled it goes further and hits that function. You saved me, thanks man!!

Comment: Though now the question is: why does this cause a crash in 4.1?

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

The error is listed in my original post: Illegal argument exception - requested provider network doesn't exist. HUH?? i'll research this and post the answer here as a final note.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the logcat output to a text file, you should be able to read it there, although I'm not positive. Just open a terminal window, navigate to the directory with your adb executable (unless it is in your PATH) and type:

`adb logcat -d > logcat.txt`

Another useful command for clearing logcat's contents is:

`adb logcat -c`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in 2.2+

```
    try {
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```