# Error in LoadLibrary: _ZNSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE6resizeEjw

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, loadlibrary

**Overview**
Trying to compile a lib.so with Android NDK r9d for using native code in my Android app. Since the lib.so is a big thirdparty with lot of dependences, I have not done the typical NDK project (with Android.mk and so on); Instead, I have used the standard compile.sh that comes with the lib sources and make pertinent changes on it to use NDK toolchain.
Finally, lib.so is compiled without errors.

**Problem**
When I test lib.so in my Android app I get "rare" (for me) errors. Here LogCat (if somebody knows how to "expand" the "... 15 more" message, I'll do it):

```
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.shalafisoft.mediatabplus.AboutActivity.onCreate(AboutActivity.java:37)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1307]:  1918 cannot locate '_ZNSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE6resizeEjw'...
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.shalafisoft.mediainfo.MediaInfoLib.<clinit>(MediaInfoLib.java:6)
04-29 11:51:47.690: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    ... 15 more
```

Here the class to load the library (line 6 is LoadLibrary).

```
public class MediaInfoLib {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mediainfoMIO");
    }

    public native String pruebaJNI();
}
```

**Thigs I have found or done**

- I have googled the id _ZW... and it seems to be related with /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so. This is all I know.
- I have googled the error and sometimes people say is something related with arch; I usually put lib.so inside libs/armeabi but I have tried libs/armeabi-v7a too with same result.

**More details**

- For compiling lib.so I use Ubuntu 12.10 x86 with Android NDK r9d
- For programming Android app I use Eclipse ADT under Windows 8 x64
- For testing Android app I use my phone Samsung Galaxy S3 (no emulator)

Comment: Decode mangled names with `c++filt`.  The symbol in the question title decodes to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::resize(unsigned int, wchar_t)`.  Makes it easier to search for.  The "... 15 more" are already shown above it; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901767/eclipse-logcat-window-cuts-off-exception-stack-traces/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have search about std::basic_string... error related to NDK or Android and I cannot find anything useful. It looks like I need to use or rebuild an specific libstdc++ and attaches it to my lib.so, but I don't know how to do it. I really would appreciate more help on this topic :(
And about "... 15 more"; thanks for your answer. I didn't know that